# TypeError: resolver.resolve is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack, terminal, solidity, truffle

When trying to truffle compile smart contracts and deploy them to an RPC testnet, I keep encountering

> TypeError: resolver.resolve is not a function
> at Profiler. (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/truffle/5.3.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/profiler.js:55:1).

In visual studio code I can't find `resolver.resolve` anywhere in my code and even cloning projects straight from github it always displays this message when truffle compiling. I have searched everywhere for the resolution and tried debugging myself in the terminal and my current thinking is it's a webpack error but I can't figure out how to solve it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which solidity compiler version are you using? Also which solidity version is your code?

Comment: Compiler is latest version and all code is ^0.8.0, extremely confusing problem.  Every attempt I've made to rectify the problem results in "TypeError: resolver.resolve is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I was also in same situation then i find the solution. Follow these steps

- Remove **node_modules** directory & **package-lock.json** (Not package.json)
- Go to your cli & run **npm install** command
- You are done

Hope this solve your problem